# Write function in tjavarow of Talend

Tags: function, talend

I have my tjavarow code thats doing repeated operation on columns inside the component, I could really use a function construct to format the strings.

is there a way to use functions inside tjavarow component of Talend?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

In talend, you can write your own function in routines and import that class in your talend job `tjava` or `tjavarow` components and call that function.

[Here you can find sample for user defined function in Talend](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Creating+a+user+routine+and+call+it+in+a+Job)

Comment: Thank you. Just what I wanted to hear :)

Comment: Note that the link is dead, but the article can be found by searching "Creating an user routine and call it in a Job".